# Join two files each with two columns that have multiple columns are matched

Tags: text-processing, join

I have two files

File A

```
MUREX_2089975   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -308410
MUREX_2097300   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7751
MUREX_2097474   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -140062
MUREX_2097928   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 46504
MUREX_2099168   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 38906
MUREX_2102690   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -139992
MUREX_2106241                   
MUREX_2106570                   
MUREX_2106577                   
MUREX_2107869                   
MUREX_748219    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7743
MUREX_777665    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7750
MUREX_778819    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7743
```

File B

```
MUREX_2089975   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -296889
MUREX_2097300   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7450
MUREX_2097474                   
MUREX_2097928   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 44699
MUREX_2099168                   
MUREX_2102690   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -134474
MUREX_2106241   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7450
MUREX_2106570   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -14942
MUREX_2106577   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -14942
MUREX_2107869   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7450
MUREX_748219    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7444
MUREX_777665    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7453
MUREX_778819    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7444
```

Code that I am using:

```
join -t, -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -o auto FileA FileB
```

What I want is basically to compare column 6 from each file while full fill out column 1 to 5.

Expected Outcome

```
MUREX_2089975   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -308410 -296889
MUREX_2097300   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7751    7450
MUREX_2097474   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -140062 
MUREX_2097928   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 46504   44699
MUREX_2099168   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 38906   
MUREX_2102690   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -139992 -134474
MUREX_2106241   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD         7450
MUREX_2106570   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD         -14942
MUREX_2106577   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD         -14942
MUREX_2107869   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD         7450
MUREX_748219    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7743    7444
MUREX_777665    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7750    7453
MUREX_778819    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7743    7444
```

Actual Outcome

```
MUREX_2089975   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -308410 :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -296889
MUREX_2097300   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7751    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7450
MUREX_2097474   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -140062                 
MUREX_2097928   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 46504   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 44699
MUREX_2099168   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 38906                   
MUREX_2102690   :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -139992 :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -134474
MUREX_2106241                                                       :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7450
MUREX_2106570                                                       :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -14942
MUREX_2106577                                                       :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD -14942
MUREX_2107869                                                       :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7450
MUREX_748219    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7743    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7444
MUREX_777665    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7750    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7453
MUREX_778819    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7743    :SBE Zinc Non-Option    118510  metals  USD 7444
```

edit1: 
One example of how the the data actually looks like:

```
 MUREX_990422,:SBE Zinc Non-Option,118510,metals,USD,15501
```

Comment: Your `join` command uses `-t,` to indicate you want to separate fields on a comma.  But there are no commas in the files.  And column 6 of both files are "metals".  I guess you mean column 8, but what more is missing here?  Using your command I just get all the lines from both files, as the entire line is considered a key, not the output you get.

Comment: Hi Jeff, it's actually comma delimited, and :SBE Zinc Non-Option is one field. The key is the first column, i.e. MUREX_2106570.

Comment: So could you include examples of what your files _actually_ look like?

Comment: it would be something like this                                                 MUREX_778819,:SBE Zinc Non-Option,118510,metals,USD,7743

Comment: did you try `join -t, -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,.1.5,1.6,2.1 FileA FileB`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that can be done directly with *join*.  What you can do is first extract a file that contains all the keys and the columns 1-5, to use as a start of each line.  Then you can use *join* to put the two numbers at the end.

What does the lines that only contain the join field look like in reality?  Is it just the field, or is it the field with commas after?  In the former case, you could do something like this

```
awk -F , 'NF > 1 {print}' fileA fileB | cut -d, -f1-5 | sort -u | \
join -t, -o 0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.6 - fileA | \
join -t, -o 0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.6 - fileB
```